# When is Morrie's Law a rational number

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I recently stumbled across Morrie's law after noticing that $\sin(20)$ x $\sin(40)$ x $\sin(80)=\frac{1}{8}$. $$\\$$ It's a simple proof to show that, in general: $$\prod_{i=0}^{k}\cos(2^ix)=\frac{\sin(2^{k+1}x)}{2^{k+1}\sin(x)} $$
This led me to think about when the R.H.S is a rational number. For the case where $\sin x, x, \sin(2^{k+1}x)$ are $\in\mathbb{Q}$, I can show that the only solution set is: $k\in\mathbb{N}, x=\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{2}$, but I'm unsure about how to deal with the other cases, I've looked at Niven's Theorem but this doesn't account for the other cases. I've also seen a result that for all rational, $x$, $\sin(x)$ is irrational, is this true (when $x=30, \sin(x)=\frac{1}{2}$) which is rational, see discussion thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/4gh1i4/is_sinx_where_x_is_rational_always_an_irrational/? $$\\$$ In particular, I want to know how to find rational solutions when $x$ is rational but $\sin{x}$ isn't rational, and similar conditions on $\sin(2^{k+1}x)$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I've also seen a result ... is this true (when $x=30$, $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}$)":  You seem to be mixing up [radians and degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) here. We have $\sin(30^\circ)  = \frac{1}{2}$ and $30^\circ = \frac{2\pi}{360}\cdot 30$ is irrational.

Comment: Well, it's clearly going to be rational whenever $2^{k+1}x \equiv x \mod 360$, as then the R.H.S. just cancels to be $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$. Also, is the multiplicand supposed to be $\cos (2^{i}x)$ or $\sin (2^{i}x)$?

Comment: To further add, the reason that $\sin (20) \sin (40) \sin (80) = 1/8$ is because this equals $\prod_{i=0}^{k=2} \sin (2^{i}20) = \dfrac{\sin (8 \cdot 20)}{8 \sin (20)} = \dfrac{\sin (160)}{8 \sin (20)}$. Note that $\sin (160) = \sin (20)$ as they are reflections of each other on the unit circle over the y-axis and thus the y-values are preserved. So this could lead to another technique to categorize when these products are rational.

Comment: Ah yes, I confused radians and degrees there, thank you. Also, thanks for the suggestions, I've started trying to implement them so I will post if I make more progress - and no, the multipicand is $\cos(2^ix)$, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MorriesLaw.html

Answer (score 1):

More than degrees and radians are mixed up.  Most particularly $\sin 20^\circ \cdot\sin 40^\circ \cdot \sin 80^\circ$ (angles in degrees) does not equal $\frac{1}{8}$. (It is $\frac{\sqrt 3}{8}$.)

Comment: Hi, welcome on the MathSE! This site supports Latex, just type `$5\cdot 5$` and you get $5\cdot 5$.